# Android Compose navigation: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm trying to create a small app that lists the PDF documents in the `Download` folder and when a document is clicked, I want it show a composable with the document for the user to see.
However, I'm getting the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/document/file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Get_Started_With_Smallpdf.pdf } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0xb86ce466) route=documentList}`

This is my `NavHost` definition:

```
NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "documentList"
        ) {
            composable("documentList") {
                DocumentList(
                    documentList = documentList ?: emptyList(),
                    onDocumentClicked = { uri ->
                        navController.navigate("document/$uri")
                    })
            }
            composable(
                "document/{documentUri}",
                arguments = listOf(navArgument("documentUri") {
                    type = NavType.ParcelableType(Uri::class.java)
                })
            ) { navBackStackEntry ->
                navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getParcelable<Uri>("documentUri")
                    ?.let { documentUri ->
                        PdfDocumentView(uri = documentUri)
                    }
            }
        }
```

I have tried to encode the URI to a String before passing, so I don't have to fiddle with NavType.ParcelableType`but with a`NavType.StringType` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You use special characters inside your argument string, which conflicts with how Jetpack Compose Navigation parses your destination route.

Encoding/decoding the argument could be a solution, for instance using Gson or Base64.